# deletion of first two element of array declared statically not working

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I am under a situation in a c that suppose i have code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int size=8;
 int  data[18]={12,9,1,7,4,5,3,11};
 int i,newS;
 printf("check1 \n");
 newS= size+1;
 data[newS]=data[0] +data[1];
 printf("news %d  \n",data[newS]);
 printf("check2 \n");
   for(i=0;i<21;i++)
        {
          if (data[i] <data[newS] ) 
            {
             printf("check3 \n");
              data[newS+1]= data[newS] +data[i] ;
              newS++;
            }   
            else
            {
             printf("check4 \n");
            }
        }
     for(i=0;i<21;i++)
     {
     printf("%d  ",data[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

I expect it to produce result like this : 1`2  9  1  7  4  5  3  11 21  33  42  43  50  54  59  62  73  18  18  8`. **But i don't know why it has one "0" just after "11".How to remove this zero ?**
The output obtained by corresponding code is this (which is not expected):

```
12  9  1  7  4  5  3  11  0  21  33  42  43  50  54  59  62  73  18  18  8
```

Comment: I formatted your code, but didn't really go through it so I can't comment specifically on an answer... but based on the sheer size of your post, I would recommend trying to break this down into a smaller, more palatable question(s).

Comment: @admdrew thanks for the help, If you tell me "how to delete the first two element of statically declared array suppose i have to delete data[0].freq element and data[1].freq element of struct data[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6} such that after deletion data[0] will point to  "3" and data[1] will point to "4" (not "0" and "1" as they were doing before deletion) then i can solve my problem."But i have to do it statically". thanks

Comment: I don't know what "statically" is intended to mean in C.

Comment: @admdrew I have edited the question, and broken the problem in small, Now could you please help me in knowing why this code has "0" after "11". I expect "21" just after "11" not "0". thanks

Comment: I believe my answer, section (2), addresses the 0.

Comment: @keshlam I tried doing it but when i delete the first two element of data and then i do futher addition on the same array . it just show "0" at those indexes where elements were deleted.Any solutions for that ?

Comment: Show us the deletion code. What you've implemented isn't what I described, clearly.

Comment: Keshlam i have  done that , thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution i have made to my problem of removing zero : (below is the code for future reference of any user).

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int size=8;
 int  data[18]={12,9,1,7,4,5,3,11};
 int i,newS;
 printf("check1 \n");
 newS= size;
 data[newS]=data[0] +data[1];
 printf("news %d  \n",data[newS]);
 printf("check2 \n");
   for(i=0;i<21;i++)
        {
          if (data[i] <data[newS] ) 
            {
             printf("check3 \n");
              data[newS+1]= data[newS] +data[i] ;
              //break;
              newS++;
            }   
            else
            {
             printf("check4 \n");
            }
        }
     for(i=0;i<21;i++)
     {
     printf("%d  ",data[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) The topic of the question keeps changing. This is needlessly frustrating. If you have two questions, either express them both or break them into two separate posts.

2) Hint: What's the index of the last element of an 8-value array?

3) For delection -- restoring my original answer -- shift all the higher-indexed values downward one space in the array, and decrease the length by one.

Comment: I have solved that problem but how to delete first two element is my second question such that the element at third and fourth index will be pointed in first and second position respectively. Any idea please ?